# What is the point of naming an anonymous function in a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I came across some standards that basically said all the functions in directives and controllers in angular should be named.  I am not talking about naming functions inside the controller or directive, I am talking about in the line where the directive is being called.

Example of how I would usually write this:

```
angular.module('myModule',[])
.directive('myDirectiveName', function (){
    return{
        controller: function($scope){
            //some code
        }
    }
});
```

How this guide is asking it to be written:

```
angular.module('myModule',[])
.directive('myDirectiveName', function directiveInit(){
    return{
        controller: function controllerInit($scope){
            //some code
        }
    }
});
```

Obviously, the difference here being `directiveInit` and `controllerInit`.

What is the point of this?  Is it for better debugging errors?  I know it is not needed.  Does this make something easier?  Is it an angular specific practice?

EDIT: Is there a better title I can use for this?  I don't feel like the title is accurately reflecting what I am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well naming functions even if they don't seem necessary to be named, is a practice for maintainability resons.

One of them is to make the function trackable, for debug and profiling tools. When you are profiling your code to track performance issues, you better know the name of the function otherwise you will only see `anonymous function` which wouldn't help much on your profiling activity.

Other reason, is for code readability improvements, especially for teams. For exemple, in angularjs (v1.x) directives are very often declared like so:

```
(function(){

    angular
        .module('myModule')
        .directive('myDirectiveName', myDirectiveName);

    function myDirectiveName(){

        function controllerInit($scope){
            //some code
        }

        return{
            controller: controllerInit
        }
    }
})();
```

Which in my opinion is way more easy to read than anonymous directive constructors. Also, it make more easy to handle such thing as encapsulation and stuff.